# Images are not displaying in Django production server

Tags: django, django-admin, django-staticfiles

I uploaded a few icons to the *static/img/* directory in my Django project, which is based on the Django Admin interface. I have one testing server and one production server. Both are using
https://fra1.digitaloceanspaces.com to store static project files. To display specific icons, I created custom field in Django `ModelAdmin`:

```
    def get_type(self, obj):
        return format_html(
            '<img alt="type" src="{static_url}/img/type_icons/type-{type}.png">',
            static_url=settings.STATIC_URL,
            type=obj.type
        )
```

*project/settings.py*

- When developing locally `STATIC_URL = '/collected-static/'`.
- In development and production mode `STATIC_URL = '{}/{}/static/'.format(AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL, AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME)`.

*AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL* is *https://fra1.digitaloceanspaces.com*.
*AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME* is either `project-develop` (testing) or `project` (production). These variables are configured in deployment YAML file.

Locally and in development(testing) mode images are displayed perfectly fine this way, but inside production mode images are not displayed at all. I've tried changing the location of the files and even changing the deployment configuration, but nothing seems to help getting the icons to show up in production.

*/collected-static/img/type-object_type.png* (example of icon *img src* on localhost - **OK**)
*https://fra1.digitaloceanspaces.com/project-develop/static/img/type-object_type.png* (example of icon *img src* on testing server - **OK**)
*https://fra1.digitaloceanspaces.com/project/static/img/type-object_type.png* (example of icon *img src* in production - **NOT DISPLAYING**)

I would like to hear your opinion on this problem I am having. I've been struggling with this for quite some time. Perhaps there is a better way to handle static files in Django Admin.

Answer (score 0):

- checking the permission of the static directory on a production server
- if you are using a web server like Nginx to serve the static directory will be useful